# Spring Data JDBC Kotlin NoSuchMethod error: Dialect.getIdGeneration()

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-data

I'm writing a very simple Spring Data JDBC repository in Kotlin (using Postgres as the database):

```
data class Label(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column( columnDefinition = "uuid", updatable = false )
    val id: UUID,
    val name: String
)

@Repository
interface LabelRepository: CrudRepository<Label, UUID> {}
```

When I do repository save:

```
val l = Label(id = UUID.randomUUID(), name = "name")
labelRepo.save(l)
```

It works fine. But since `id` is not null Spring Data JDBC will always treat it as an "update" to an existing label entity instead of creating a new one with generated ID.

So I changed `id: UUID` to `id: UUID?` And having `val l = Label(id = null, name = "name")`

But call the same `save()` method gives me:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.IdGeneration org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.Dialect.getIdGeneration()'
```

I have tried a solution here: https://jivimberg.io/blog/2018/11/05/using-uuid-on-spring-data-jpa-entities/
But it didn't work, still gives me the same error

Wondering what's the cause of this and why this error pops up only when I change `UUID` to `UUID?`?

Answer (score 0):

nvm, turns out I have to use the `implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc")` dependency instead of `implementation("org.springframework.data:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc:2.1.3")`